# Combining strings separated by quotation marks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following:

[image]

The words are separated by the quotation marks and on next lines even thought it is in a single line.

How would I comebine them all into one set of quotation mark?

I can target them by `nextSibling`:

```
var sphs = $("#" + v_id + "").get(0).nextSibling;
var sh_con = sphs.textContent;
```

But there are always separated.

Comment: The quotation marks are just indicating that those are text nodes (they are not actually part of any value). So are you basically asking how to merge multiple consecutive text nodes? In that case the title of your question is *very* misleading. Why do you want to do that anyway?

Comment: That's exactly it. I am manipulating the strings in between `</span>` and `</div>` and having multiple text nodes are causing issues and I want to check if it is the text nodes that are causing the problem and not something else.

Comment: If you just want to test it then simply delete all but one text node via the DOM inspector? If multiple text nodes cause problems then the best course of action would be to avoid creating multiple nodes in the first place. Or are you not creating the nodes?

Comment: I wish it is simple as that. :P Maybe I will try it and see if it works. =) Thanks thought! Otherwise I might use `normalize`.

Comment: Well, just for testing. After you found out whether having multiple text nodes is the actual issue, you can consider solutions for fixing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.normalize()` should do the [trick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/normalize) for those who are interested in for whatever reason that might be. =)

> The Node.normalize() method puts the specified node and all of its sub-tree into a "normalized" form. In a normalized sub-tree, no text nodes in the sub-tree are empty and there are no adjacent text nodes.

Comment: What exactly is `this` in your example? What does `normalize` do exactly?